# I need to make a function that is able to see which is the biggest number it can have when you insert a number

Tags: javascript, function

I need to make a function that is able to see which is the biggest number it can have when you insert a number, using that number as the limit of string length.

I have tried making one, but when I try it out, the jsfiddle tab freezes.

```
   function myProg() {
    var n = 3;
    alert(largestNumber(n));
    var m = 10;
    alert(candies(n, m));
}

myProg();

function largestNumber(n) {
    var i = 0
    while (i.length != parseInt(n)+1) {
    i++
    }
    return i - 1

}
```

I just wanted to know if this was correct and if in any other circumstance it would run just fine. Also, if you check above, there is a candies function. That one is function that I need to do. It has to divide m / n, but without decimal, instead leaving a residue. Module hasn't worked thus. Appreciate the help!

Comment: `Number` `i` does not have a `.length` property

Comment: and how do i do that so that the number might have a string length

Comment: The largest number with length *n* is `10^n - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

To get a number's length you can convert it into a string then get its length:

```js
var i = 666;
var j = i.toString().length;
console.log(j);
// result: 3
```

Be careful, don't write "length()" but just "length" (it's a property, no a method)

Answer (score 0):

`Number` `i` does not have a `.length` property, use `i` without `.length`

```js
function myProg() {
  var n = 3;
  alert(largestNumber(n));
  var m = 10;
  alert(largestNumber(n, m));
}

myProg();

function largestNumber(n, m) {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < (m && parseInt(m) + 1 || parseInt(n) + 1)) {
    i++
  }
  return i - 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to copy the variable `i` . Convert it to a string `.toString()` and then you will be able to `.length` that copy.

```
function largestNumber(n) {
var i = 0
var j = i
while (j.toString().length != parseInt(n)+1) {
i++
}
return i - 1}
```